# ArangoDB - Swap _to and _from values for edge using AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is there a clean way to swap the `_to` and `_from` values for an edge using AQL? According to [Arango's documentation on Edges](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/graphs-edges.html):

> To change edge endpoints you would need to remove old document/edge and insert new one. Other fields can be updated as in default collection.

So what I was able to come up with was a query that looks like this:

```
FOR edge IN edge_collection
    FILTER [some criteria]
    LET tempEdge = KEEP(edge, ATTRIBUTES(edge, true))
    LET newEdge = MERGE([{'_key':edge._key}, {'_from':edge._to}, {'_to':edge._from}, tempEdge])
    REPLACE newEdge IN edge_collection
    RETURN NEW
```

To explain my own solution a bit, I used the `ATTRIBUTES(edge, true)` function to get the names of all of the Attributes on the Edge, and the `true` parameter removed the internal attributes (like `_key`, `_id`, `_to`, etc.). Read more about `ATTRIBUTES` [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#attributes).

Then the `KEEP(edge, [attributes])` function returns a new Document that only has the Attributes specified in the given array, which thanks to the `ATTRIBUTES` function in this case, is everything but the internal fields. Read more about `KEEP` [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#keep).

Then I use the `MERGE` function to combine the `_key` from the original edge, swap the `_to`  and `_from` values, and all of the non-internal attributes. Read more about `MERGE` [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#merge).

Lastly, I use `REPLACE` which removes the original edge and adds the new one in, just like Arango requires. Read more about `REPLACE` [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-replace.html).

Like I said, this appears to work, but the `MERGE` in particular feels like the wrong way to go about doing what I did. Is there an easier way to set values on an Object? For instance, something that would let me just make a call similar to: `tempEdge._from = edge._to`?

Comment: The statement `To change edge endpoints you would need to remove old document/edge and insert new one.` is obsolete since 3.0 IIRC. It's a leftover from the past that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler solution:

```
FOR edge IN edge_collection
    FILTER [some criteria]
    UPDATE edge WITH {_from: edge._to, _to: edge._from} IN edge_collection
    RETURN NEW
```

`_from` and `_to` can be updated (in contrast to the system attributes `_id`, `_key` and `_rev`), so you don't need to replace the whole document. And since `UPDATE` merges the changes into the existing document, you only need to specify the new values for `_from` and `_to`.